# How to check an image's format in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So let's assume I have a file stored somewhere and it can be either a `jpeg` file or a `png` file, what is the way to check what it is?

Should I simply check the extension? Or should I read the file's binary signature? Or how do I do it?

Comment: That's a very broad question. I mean in absence of any other criteria either of those approaches would work. Criteria like "how likely is the file extension to be wrong?" If the chances of the file extension being wrong are practically 0 then use the file extension. But without some further criteria to qualify the question it's really hard to say which is "better".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Update: 4/2/2016 to include **.JPG validation**.*

There's a fairly popular hex package [Arc](https://hex.pm/packages/arc) that might work for you. Extracted from Arc:

```
def validate({file, _}) do
  ~w(.jpg .jpeg .gif .png .JPG) |> Enum.member?(Path.extname(file.file_name))
end
```

Comment: Author of `arc` here, this validation method has since been updated to also downcase the path, so `.JPG` files will match as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could extract the Magic number of the file and analyse it. That's fairly simple once you have the format specs